# Allow backslash on API jSon

Tags: c#, json, api, .net-core

I just create a simple `Insert` API with C# .NET Core v5.
The format like:

```
{
    groupname: string,
    groupdescription: string,
    filedirectory: string
}
```

On the `filedirectory`, I have to put the value like, `E:\FilesDirectory\image.png`

But It shows me an error like:

```
'U' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped.
```

`U` is the character after backslash that I tried to execute the API. `E:\Unform\blahblachblah`

The API code:

```
public async Task<int> InsertUpdateProper(modelGroup modelGroup)
{
    string SP = "sp_insertupdateGroup";
    parameters.AddDynamicParams(modelGroup);
    var result = await mySqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(SP, parameters, commandType: mysp);
    return result;
}
```

Above will be called in Controller.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "I have to put the value like" - you can't modify it in anyway?  Escaping the backslashes with another backslash seems to work for me.

Comment: So hows the idea @TimothyG., ? The value for it is a path. How can I modify it? please let me know, I don't understand.

Comment: Where is the path coming from? Is it being produced by your code somewhere? If so, wherever that occurs just make it `E:\\FilesDirectory\\image.png` - your POST Body denotes it is a string, and `E:\\FilesDirectory\\image.png` is a valid string.  You won't even have to un-escape it afterwards for IO operations, as they accept that as a valid path, meaning `Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\\FilesDirectory\\MyDirectory");` will work as an example.

Comment: Hi @TimothyG., the value came from Front-End that consumed my API. So you meant, if possible, the Front-End should throw a modified value (double-backslash)?

Comment: @TimothyG., could you post as your answer please? So I can accept it. Your suggestion would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your front end that is sending the POST body needs to properly escape the `filedirectory` property using `\` to escape the backslashes:

```json
{
   "filedirectory": "E:\\SomeFolder\\SomePicture.jpg"
}
```

You won't even have to un-escape it afterwards in you API for IO operations, as they accept that as a valid path, meaning `Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\\FilesDirectory\\MyDirectory");` will work as an example.